# Get value of clicked element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to get value of element that was clicked? `event.target.value`  shows `undefined`.

```
import React from "react";

class Home extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            products: [],
            isLoaded: false,
            value: ""
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

   componentDidMount(){
       fetch("/home")
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(result =>{
           return(
               this.setState({
                   products: result,
                   isLoaded: true
               })
           )                                            
       })
   }

   handleClick(event){
       console.log(event.target) //shows full element
       console.log(event.target.value) //shows undefined    
   }
   
   render(){
      if(!this.state.isLoaded){
          return(
              <h1>Loading...</h1>
          )
      }
      return <div>{this.state.products.map(elements => 
                <div 
                        key={elements.id} 
                        onClick={this.handleClick}
                        value={elements.name}    
                        >
                        {elements.name}
                </div>
                )}
                <h1>Name: {this.state.value}</h1>
            </div>;
    }
}
export default Home;
```

Comment: Hey, @mirzad, as `event.target` is the clicked `<div>` there is no value in `<div>`

Comment: An alternative to all the answers is using a `data-value` attribute in the element. Then in the event handler use `event.target.getAtttribute("data-value")`. Yet another alternative is to bind the value as a parameter to the event handler: `onClick={handleClick.bind(this, elements.name)}`. As you can see a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div>` tag doesn't have a value, you need to pass the `value` prop yourself:

```
<div 
  key={elements.id} 
  onClick={() => this.handleClick(elements.name)} // Pass as parameter
  value={elements.name} // Can be removed if there's no other purpose
  >
  {elements.name}
</div>
```

And in the function:

```
handleClick(value){
   console.log(value) // this is the value
}
```

Comment: `value={elements.name}` is not needed.

Comment: Maybe not for the purpose of getting it on click, but it could still be used as a prop. No harm in keeping it there.

Answer (score 1):

A `div`component does not any `value` property, you should do something like this to achieve what you need:

```
<div
  key={elements.id}
  onClick={() => this.handleClick(element.name)}
>
  {elements.name}
</div>
```